# AlethZero crashes after informing that it "couldn't find requested block"

Tags: alethzero

I have installed Release 1.2.9 ("The Village Idiot") of cpp-ethereum on a windows 7 machine. It downloaded the chainblock overnight and I experimented with mining this morning. My PC became non responsive and I had to reset my system. After reboot, I tried running AlethZero again but all I got is a console message in the title of this question and a message window informing that AlethZero.exe has crashed (pic below).

Can anyone point me in the right direction for resolving this issue? I would hate having to download a 25GB blockchain again.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid to have to tell you that AlethZero is being discontinued, so I would recommend that switch to ethminer right now if you are having problems:

https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/08/c-dev-update-summer-edition/

Also note that Genoil's ethminer fork is better supported than the official ethminer right now, so you are best starting there:

- https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/313
- https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/issues/315

As well as StackExchange, you can also check out:

- https://reddit.com/r/ethermining
- https://gitter.im/ethereum/minercommunitysupport
- http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/mining.html

Best wishes and sorry that you're hitting issues :-(

Comment: Thank you. Will `ethminer` or `Genoil` be able to work with the data downloaded by AlethZero?

Comment: No - you will need to re-download, I am afraid.